# Function return values within BASH if statements

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have looked at various ways on here handle function return values within BASH if-then statements, but none seem to work. Here is what I've got

```
 function is_cloned()
 {
      if [ -d $DIR_NAME ]
      then
           return $SUCCESS
      fi
      return $FAILURE
 }
```

It will work if I call it on its own and check the return value like:

```
 is_cloned
 retval=$?
 if [ $retval -eq $FAILURE ] 
 then
      ...
 fi
```

How can I use the function call within the if statement? Or is there no way at all to take advantage of the return values?

Comment: `if` is always checking the return value of a command. Note that the `[` *is* a command. Try `help [` to see. Instead of `[` you can use any command or function, like this: `if my_cmd ; then do this ; else do that ; `

Comment: Unless you have some very specific values of `SUCCESS` and `FAILURE` that you are using in place of `0` and `1`, just use `is_cloned () { [ -d "$DIR_NAME" ]; }`.

Answer (score 11):

`if` statements in Bash can use the exit code of functions directly.
So you can write like this:

```
if is_cloned
then
    echo success
fi
```

If you want to check for failure, as in your posted code, you could use the `!` operator:

```
if ! is_cloned
then
    echo failure
fi
```

By the way, your `is_cloned` function too can rely more on exit codes,
you can write like this:

```
is_cloned() {
    [ -d "$DIR_NAME" ]
}
```

This works, because the exit code of a function is the exit code of the last executed command,
and the exit code of `[ ... ]` is 0 if successful, non-zero otherwise (= failure).

Also remember to double-quote variable names used as command arguments,
as I did `DIR_NAME` here.

Comment: Sort of defeats the point of the function at all, may as well just test DIR_NAME.

Comment: @123 Just because it's simple, that doesn't mean it's useless. The function encapsulates a specific logic. If the logic needs to be improved later, it can be done by modifying just the function, leaving the rest of the program alone.

Comment: Will the first methodology you listed even rely on error codes or will it just execute that code if the function call doesn't exit the script?

Comment: @basil It's called "exit code", not "error code". The `if is_cloned` statement uses the exit code of the `is_cloned` function. The exit code can be in an explicit `return` statement, or it's the exit code of the last executed command. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @janos Encapsulation for the sake of it unnecessarily increases code complexity.

Comment: @123, ...there's a judgment call to be made there, to be sure. *However*, if `is_cloned` makes it more obvious to a reader what the intent behind a statement is than it would otherwise be from context, that's adding value in and of itself. (Whether that value is sufficient... again, we're in contextually-dependent judgment-call territory)

Comment: @123 I definitely prefer to read `if is_cloned` than `if [ -d DIR_NAME ]` when reading a main program. If I'm new to the code it's far easier to get what the code is doing and in addition it is self explaining without a comment. If I'm interested in how the program decides whether *something* is cloned or not I just need to look at the implementation of the function. To be honest, besides some trivial shell scripts, there are very few to no reasons to not encapsulate `is_cloned` (for example).

Comment: @123 If the name of the function would be `dir_exists`, I would agree that it would be unnecessary encapsulation.