# How to compare result of function in if statement using idiomatic bash

Tags: bash

I have a function which returns one of three values, 0, 1 or 2

I want to check the return value of the function in an if statement.

How can I do this in idiomatic bash?

This works, but looks very wrong to me:

```
vercomp $prev $new
result=$?
if [[ result -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo "Greater than" 
elif [[ result -eq 2 ]]; then
  echo "Less than"
fi
```

How can I consolidate this code and use the function directly in the if statement instead of using the intermediate result variable and how can I access the return value without using $? ?

Everything I have tried has failed.

For example even this fails - why?

```
result=vercomp $prev $new
if [[ result -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo "Greater than" 
elif [[ result -eq 2 ]]; then
  echo "Less than"
fi
```

And this fails:

```
if [[ vercomp $prev $new -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo "Greater than" 
elif [[ vercomp $prev $new -eq 2 ]]; then
  echo "Less than"
fi
```

This fails:

```
if [[ $(vercomp $prev $new) -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo "Greater than" 
elif [[ $(vercomp $prev $new) -eq 2 ]]; then
  echo "Less than"
fi
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I improve my working code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash functions return exit codes back to the shell which can be retrieved from the value of `$?` as in your first case. You need to read through [Return value in a Bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17336915/5291015) to understand the difference between exit code and return value from function.

As explained in detail in multiple answers including [Function return values within BASH if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46694112/5291015) you can directly use the function invocation in the `if` statement. A return code of `0` from the function would assert the if condition to true. So you can do something like

```
if vercomp "$prev" "$new"; then
    printf 'return code zero \n'
else
    case $? in
      1) printf 'return code one \n' ;;
      2) printf 'return code two \n' ;;
      *) printf "unknown return code $?\n" ;;
    esac
fi
```

As for the failure cases

1. This `result=vercomp $prev $new` is *not* even a valid function execution in bash but an incorrect variable assignment. To run function and store the output in a variable, you need to use [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) `$(..)` You need to have written it as `result=$(vercomp "$prev" "$new")`
2. And `if [[ vercomp $prev $new -eq 1 ]]; then` again is an *incorrect* invocation of the function. Everything inside `[[..]]` is evaluated in a string context. So the test operator `[[` just treats it as incorrect operation and would have thrown a parser error
3. `[[ $(vercomp $prev $new) -eq 1 ]]` is also incorrect. All commands in bash return an exit code to the shell the program is invoked from. The command substitution inherently returns the code to the shell via `$?` but the `-eq` operator checks for a string value returned from the invocation. Since the construct does not put any contents to stdout, there won't anything to match with 1 or 2. If you done soemthing like `[[ $(vercomp "$prev" "$new"; printf "$?") -eq 1 ]]` it would have worked, but again not a good practice.

Comment: Is there anyway to make it work without using the $? variable?

Comment: Yes but you can, using my first approach `if <func>`, but that won't get you what the other return codes are. but what is your real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Even with your answer ```if <func>``` you still need to use ```$?``` for any non-zero result. It seems strange to me that there is no way to check the return value without using ```$?```. But maybe that is just how Bash is, and it is my lack of understanding which makes it look confusing.

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
case $? in
  0) echo "one";;
  1) echo "two";;
  2) echo "three";;
esac
```

---

See: `help case`